# Function to resize arrays and assign values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, resize

I'm having some trouble with a function that I'm trying to write as part of a project in C. I'm trying to write a function that not only resizes an array, but also assigns values to the new elements of the array.

For example if `A = [a, b, c]` and it needs to be doubled. The array needs to be re-sized to
`[a, a+b/2, b, b+c/2, c, 3c/2]`. If `A = [a, b, c, d, e, f]` the array should be re-sized to `[a, c, e]`. Any re-factoring of arrays is by some multiple of 2.

This is the offending bit of code.

```
void re_size_array(double *A, long n, long nx){
  double *T;
  long i, j;
  long m;
  T = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*nx);
  if(nx > n){
    m = nx/n;
    double k;
    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
      k = (A[i+1] - A[i])/m;
      for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
        T[i*m + j] = A[i] + j*k;
      }
    }
    k = A[n-1]/m;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
      T[(n-1)*m + i] = A[n-1] + i*k;
    }
    A = (double*)realloc(A, sizeof(double)*nx);
    if(A == NULL){
      printf("Array has failed to re-size\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    double *tmp = T;
    A = T;
    T = tmp;
    free(T);
  }
  if(nx < n){
    m = n/nx;
    for(i = 0; i < nx; i++){
      T[i] = A[i*m];
    }
    A = (double*)realloc(A, sizeof(double)*nx);
    if(A == NULL){
      printf("Array has failed to re-size\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    double *temp = T;
    A = T;
    T = temp;
    free(T);
  }
}
```

I'm stuck as to why this doesn't work, I've printed out the values which are supposed to be assigned and they are all correct. I have tried swapping the pointers differently but I still get no viable result.

Instead when I try to re-size the data to a larger nx it results in the same process as `A = realloc(A, nx*sizeof(double))`. If I try to decrease the size, nothing happens.

Comment: Why does `void f(int i) {i = 5;} int main() {int x = 0; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` not print 5?

Comment: Any reason to avoid meaningfull names for variables? Also you should not use single-letter upper case names. All-uppercase in general is used for macro constants only.

Comment: There is no array in your code. There is a reason a _pointer_ is not called "array".

Comment: Casting the return of `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` is very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

- `A = T` is not visible outside of the function. If you want that, then pass a pointer to the double pointer (`double **`) in your function signature.
- You should `return A;` at the very end and call the function like `A = re_size_array(A, n, nx)`

hth :)

Comment: I added your suggestions and it seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you :)